# How to access the map which is given by using the reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, maps, omnet++

I need the size of the map which is given by the reference. What does the reference point at? If it is the reference to all the key values and mapped values, can I print them all?

```
const std::map<std::string, cModule*>& getManagedHosts()  { return hosts; }
```

I am trying to get the size of getManagedHosts() but it results in the value zero.

```
const std::map<std::string, cModule*>& allHosts = tr->getManagedHosts(); 
 unsigned int numHosts = allHosts.size();
```

Comment: If you get zero through a reference, then there's also a zero on the original. Once you change `hosts` map to have some data, `allHosts` would stop showing zero size.

Comment: thanks, how can I print the mapped values from this reference, so that I can check if its empty? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: If the size is zero, it is empty. Trying to print values from an empty map is futile.

Comment: "What does the reference point at" - a reference is not a pointer.  I have read it discussed as an 'alias', but I'm not sure that helps.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN  I am not sure understanding this clearly    

const std::map<std::string, cModule*>& getManagedHosts()  { return hosts; }

Comment: Where you define `hosts`? If it is local variable in `getManagedHosts`, it is not going to work;

Comment: hosts is defined in public, its not local. @KillzoneKid

Comment: Perhaps: An obj and a pointer can both exist: int obj; int* p = &obj; are two different things in memory, each has there own address.. A reference is a new name for an existing address. int obj; int& objRef; You can use or modify the value of obj by using either symbol. The compiler does not allocate a memory for the reference.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. The return value was zero because another function was called before it which delete all the cModules. The code is correct and giving the result when placed before delete function.

Answer (score 0):

2 cases are possible :

- the map is really empty.
- the map returned is instantieted in the scope of function getManagedHosts(), and not visible outside.